# EPlotting Scatter Plot of Multidimensional Features

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, graph

I am having problem plotting a scatter plot

I want to plot the value of Audio features on a scatter plot for clear visuals (for not i have 5 audio files in my training set - which i'll use to train KNN/SVM etc after increasing my data set)

The training_labels marked are
`[0, 0, 1, 2, 1]`

While training_feature values are

```
[
    [103.359375, [11, 36, 60, 85, 110, 134, 159, 183, 208, 232, 257, 286, 310, 335]], 
    [89.10290948275862, [11, 41, 69, 98, 127, 155, 184, 213, 241, 270, 299, 327, 356]], 
    [151.99908088235293, [7, 24, 41, 57, 73, 90, 107, 123, 140, 157, 173, 189, 206, 223, 239, 256, 272, 290, 307, 325, 343, 360, 377]], 
    [143.5546875, [39, 57, 77, 95, 114, 132, 150, 168, 186, 204, 222, 239, 256, 272, 288, 305, 322, 340]], 
    [83.35433467741936, [8, 38, 70, 101, 137, 168, 199, 230, 266, 298, 334, 365]]
]
```

Each object to be classified have 2 features called `tempo` and `beat per minute`

How can i plot this in a scatter plot?

I tried the following but it fails due to difference between sizes of x and y

```
featureA = [x[0] for x in training_features]
featureB = [x[1] for x in training_features]

plt.scatter(featureA[:2], featureB[:2])
plt.scatter(featureA[2:], featureB[2:], color='r')
plt.xlabel('Beat Frame')
plt.ylabel('Tempo')
```

This give me an error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. Help please :)

Edit: One more thing, how can i plot multiple feature i.e(>2), i want to use spectral centroid, zero crossing rate, mfcc etc, and then plot the results

Comment: You have more than 10 y-values per x value. You need to tell us what you would like to plot against what.

Comment: I have no idea tbh, i just to check how they can be visualized in a scatterplot @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ImportanceOfBeingEarnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) says, the problem is the size of the array.

For scatter you need an array with the coordinates of the points (x and y).
But featureB is an array with many values.

```
>>> print(featureB[:2])
[[11, 36, 60, 85, 110, 134, 159, 183, 208, 232, 257, 286, 310, 335],
[11, 41, 69, 98, 127, 155, 184, 213, 241, 270, 299, 327, 356]]
```

Then you need to transform training_feature to something like this:

```
points = []
for x in training_feature:
    for y in x[1]:
        points.append([x[0], y])
points = np.array(points)

points.shape # (80, 2)
```

And now if we can use plt.scatter!

```
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
```

[image: scatter_example]

I do not understand that you wanted to plot, but I hope it works for you!...